# Develop application on top of Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, plugins, electron

I would like to know if Visual Studio Code provides an API that help you develop a desktop application on top of it platform. The main idea is to do like in Eclipe RCP or IntelliJ Plateform.

I want to use the plugin system available in VS Code instead of developing my own plugin system.
Any help, any link or any information will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is more of community q and probably will be closed. anyway, short answer is no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least two ongoing projects that you can take inspiration from in this field:

- https://theia-ide.org/ by Eclipse, which is an extensible platform to develop multi-language Cloud & Desktop IDEs. In the screenshots, you'll clearly distinguish the part coming from VSCode (like the Activity Bar) and custom ones, like the flexible layout system.
- https://v2.onivim.io/ based on Vim but that should also leverage the VSCode plugins ecosystem according to the roadmap.

Comment: Onivim project seems amazing.  Thanks for the reference.