# Are there apps built on top of VSCode open source base?

Tags: visual-studio-code, web-frameworks

VSCode has a very customizable UI with Activity Bar, Sidebar, Tabs, Status Bar etc (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface); customizable via extensions and seems to have been developed without any of the common web frameworks (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/99845).

It is well maintained, works in different OSes and has automatic updates.

Even if we remove the code-editor part, there is a lot of work in that.

This makes me wonder if it is possible to write a totally different app (not a code editor) on top of VSCode. For example a Slack-like messaging app, an Obsidian-like knowledge base app, etc.

Is it possible?  Are there apps built on top of this code? Have I missed an important point that makes this idea unviable?

**EDIT:**

Some have pointed a very valid point.  Some of what I mentioned here as VSCode features are really Electron features that VSCode inherits. Having developed an Electron app (5yrs ago) I see many things in VSCode that are not in Electron (but maybe my concept of Electron is wrong).

I want to emphasize that VSCode UI (bars, tabs, etc) + its extensibility seems to be a valid development framework. And I am ignorant of anything in this sense.

**EDIT (jan/2023):**
I guess we can add [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) as a product that just did that.

Comment: *seems to have been developed without any of the common web frameworks*, you mean aside from node, chromium/electron, and a bazillion Javascript libraries?

Comment: Ok. You are right on that.

Comment: "it works on different OSes": yes, it's an electron app. It works where electron works, so that's a feature of the electron underpinning.

Comment: VSCode itself is an example of that. It's based on Electro, which is in turn bases out of the Chromium project. You can think of VSCode as a **heavily** modded Chrome browser, ultimately.

Comment: Another, somewhat unrelated example. Visual Studio (the real one, not code) is also very extensible and fundamentally a shell for loading things on top of it. SQL Server Management Studio is also a repurpose of the same IDE, also totally modded to make it manage database servers instead of developing software.

Comment: @muller You are right on that again. Maybe I should edit the question.

Comment: @Alejandro  I developed an electron app 5 yrs ago, so maybe my concept of Electron is old. But VSCode has all this UI on top of Electron.   I mean... The Active Bar, the Sidebar, Tabs... all these were things that when I developed an Electron app, I had to develop myself. VSCode has all these in a very customizable way.

Comment: If there was not Text-editor in VSCode I could develop any app just by creating customizations.  This seems interesting to me.  But maybe it is all in Electron.

Comment: Fred you might want to look up what things exist that build on the *eclipse* IDE - it's staggering! Not all things are "IDEs for textual code development", but honestly, the takeway from eclipse is "eclipse solved the 'how do I get a GUI to the technical user' problem, and bad UX decision followed when people tried to abuse the codebase meant to be used to build an IDE".

Comment: @MarcusMüller the Eclipse IDE extensions you point out are exactly what I was looking for.  I do remember (so many years ago) a myriad of apps that used eclipse as the base.

Comment: Anyone interested in moving this idea forward.  Please ping me at Github.  I would certainly join an open source effort for this.

Comment: @FredGuth I'm short on time but rather intrigued by your interest and came across it after spending time searching for apps based on VSCode or "OSS - Code" with no results. The usecases I see are non-code-centric apps that would benefit from the text editor features, like the Obsidian example you mentioned, along with webserver-dependent aspects. My personal curiosity is plaintext accounting tools (e.g. beancount) where users currently juggle the text editor, a file view/git status, a web browser window, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is very valid and I was wondering the same thing, so thanks for asking it.

One thing that VS Code gives you that Electron doesn't is a **distribution model** - the [marketplace](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension) and how new versions of your app can be detected and downloaded automatically etc. This is a big deal.

I think the disadvantages are that a very fancy UX may not be possible directly - but you have to "work around" by putting HTML within a [Web View](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview) perhaps. This is just my guess and I haven't directly tried it.

To answer your question - the only one I am aware of is [Thunder Client](https://www.thunderclient.io) - so think of [Postman](https://www.postman.com) - but as a VS Code plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I have came back to it every time I fancy this idea (which is more often than I would imagine).  The Thunder Client example (as far as my understanding go) is not exactly what I mean, because is just vscode extension that is a product. @marcusmüller comparison with the eclipse ecosystem is in line with the original idea.

Comment: @FredGuth appreciate that you keep coming back to this. and me too. I haven't dug into it much, but passing this on - I feel that codestream may be a good reference: https://github.com/TeamCodeStream/codestream - they seem to be using the "webview" approach extensively and able to re-use code across IDEs. just in case this helps

Answer (score 1):

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/67069697/314780 , which points to Eclipse Theia which uses parts from Visual Studio Code (i.e "Code - OSS") - https://theia-ide.org/ . The site links to a number of IDE-style apps built on top of it.

Comment: Thanks for the reference: the projects mentioned in this referenced question are amazing.  I loved onivim and I am very curious about ReasonML (which I didn't know).

Answer (score 0):

VS Code is an *electron* app. You might want to research what *electron* is – because you mention it: The Slack app [*is*](https://www.electronjs.org/apps/slack) built on that same framework.

So, you've just invented something that already is done, [very widely](https://www.electronjs.org/apps), in practice.

Comment: I know what electron is and I know that VSCode is an electron app. But from electron to everything that vscode provides in terms of UI there is a huge difference.

Comment: well, then I don't understand the question – when you take the code out of VS Code, you get electron.

Comment: upvoting because this is a valid point. So much, I addressed in an EDIT in the question.